# which JSON framework with ios SDK?

Tags: ios, json

There are couple of JSON frameworks. JSONKit , SBJSON , Native JSON and other. Which one is the best to use for Iphone app OR ios App and why ?

Comment: This question is pretty subjective...I would suggest asking it in a more objective way like "What are the pros and cons of X library for Y situation"?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use the built-in [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/)?

Comment: Kevin Ballard : Just newbie and trying different things thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SBJson for two years, and many Object-C API use SBJson too.
It is quite hard to compare different json apis, however SBJson is easy to use and widely used.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to target just iOS5 and above  you could try `NSJSONSerialization`

> Basically iOS 5 has a new class named NSJSONSerialization. It has a
>   static method called JSONObjectWithData:options:error that takes an
>   NSData and gives you back a Foundation object – usually an
>   NSDictionary or an NSArray depending what do you have at the top of
>   your JSON file hierarchy.

an excellent example

[from Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Comment: @user583726 no worries man, if was of use to you please upvote ;)

Comment: Thank you. That is a much better approach than adding another framework.