# how to parse json string and store the object in an array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am getting data from server it gives in response a NSString which hase json data i want that json data to be store in an array how to do this

```
      NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

       NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


       NSLog(data);

   NSData* data=[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];



     - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
      //parse out the json data
       NSError* error;
       NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];

     NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"loans"]; //2

       NSLog(@"loans: %@", latestLoans); //3
   }
```

here is the log of data which return from server

```
  [{"CodeValue":"90658","CodeDescription":"flu shot","IsActive":"1","CodeType":"CPT","CodeID":"6","UpdateDateTime":"2012-04-02 02:09:46"}]
```

Comment: what have tried so for, there are lots of tutorials for json parsing.. this is on of it go through this http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: i am new to development can u edit in mycode a little so that i may get how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [which JSON framework with ios SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021694/which-json-framework-with-ios-sdk)

Comment: i am using your given tutorial it crashes app unrecognised selecter sent to dictionary and what i have to put instead of loan object in mycode

Comment: in which ios are u building the app

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                           withObject:urlData waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: @DilshadAlmani  NSArray* latestLoans = [NSArray arrayWithArray:json];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSArray *dataArr=[data JSONValue];

for (int i=0; i<[dataArr count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict=[dataArr objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *codeV=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeValue"];
    NSString *codeD=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeDescription"];
    NSString *active=[dict valueForKey:@"IsActive"];
    NSString *codeT=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeType"];
    NSString *codeId=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeID"];
    NSString *updatedTime=[dict valueForKey:@"UpdateDateTime"];

    NSLog([dict description],nil);
}

    NSLog(@"%@", json_string);


//May this will help you out.
```

Do include the JSon library classes to your project.

I am doing in this way to insert in an array but it return o object

```
       NSDictionary *dict=[dataArr objectAtIndex:i];

        SearchCode *theObject =[[SearchCode alloc] init];


        theObject.codeValue=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeValue"];
        theObject.codeDescription=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeDescription"];
        theObject.codeType=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeType"];
        theObject.codeID=[dict valueForKey:@"CodeID"];
        theObject.UpdateDateTime=[dict valueForKey:@"UpdateDateTime"];


        NSLog(codeType);




        [cptArray addObject:theObject];
        [theObject release];
        theObject=nil;



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [cptArray count];    
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

     }
SearchCode *theObject =[cptArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=theObject.codeValue; //& so on you can access any value from "theObject" here


}
```

Comment: it is given crash terminating app due to -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73e8490
2012-04-05 10:11:06.451 EMR[483:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Try the edited code will work for you surely. You will get all the key values you are getting in json.

Comment: yes i am getting now but how may i store these values in an object array like mycptArray addObject:codeV like this

Comment: issue is that when i use this array in table view it does not show anything and when i use breakpoit in number of rws in sections it again not move to table cell

Comment: when the view is loaded it first shows table view and search button when i enter any text in searctfield and press enter then it loads arrat foundcodes with two objects how to shows again that in table view

Comment: Try the edited code having the tableview methods. Which would be useful to you

Comment: The person who have voted out, please leave comment so I can optimize my answer further and make it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more packaged solution check out: https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Its a awesome framework, to parse JSON you can just type

```
[string_here JSONValue];
```